# Push dynamic Json into Api controller action

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using documentdb for persistence and I have an asp.net core app for the front end.

I would like to be able to write an api action that accepts a Person as a post body. However, Person represents the minimum of data that the user can post up. Person will only contain properties for first name and last name. The user will be able to push up additional properties as they decide (age, middle name..., whatever they decide), as their post is just json.

Is there any way to achieve this with .net core? DocumentDb obviously supports schema less persistence, so obviously not a problem. But I don't know of a way to make the api flexible here.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided your code, so I am going to assume a few things and you will have to adapt them.

Since DocumentDb supports strongly typed objects as well as schemaless (dynamic) objects, the most sensible thing we can do is use the `dynamic` type:

```
using (client = new DocumentClient(new Uri("endpoint://to/your/db"), authKey))
{
    //jsonObj is the object passed into your controller of type string
    //collection is your DocumentDb collection
    dynamic somePerson =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonObj);
    await client.CreateDocumentAsync(collection.SelfLink, somePerson);
}
```

Read more about `dynamic` here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic

Comment: This looks reasonable. I have no code to handle this aspect at the moment, it is new. Your suggestions seems fine as far as passing the json to the controller as a string, but if I do that, is there then a way to check the json string conforms to the minimum of the Person strongly typed object? i.e. check the json contains the first and last name properties and then validate those values e.g. Model.IsValid(converted json...). If I pass it as string I lose all the built in validation using DataAnnotations.